# How to define virtual hosts in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have:
- root account on a machine where I've just installed Apache 2.2 and other stuff. 
- The machine has a public IP but resides behind a firewall and
- only ports 80 and 22 are open. 
- I have registered a domain (say example.com) that translates to the public IP of the machine, but
- I don't have access to DNS servers where my example.com is registered.

I need to set up a few web based services on the machine, e.g. a user forum, git repository with WebDAV, etc. I presume I can do this with virtual hosts, right?

But:

1) is it possible to set up 2-3 virtual hosts without a divine intervention of our system administrator? This actually I would like to avoid it at all costs

2) I the answer for 1) is NO, what is the easiest way to  set up virtual hosts. For example, can I register subdomain1.example.com, subdomain2.example.com etc in other DNS servers?

Comment: Are you afraid of sysadmins?  We're all bark and no bite...

Comment: A better question for you to ask might be "How can I stop worrying and learn to love my sysadmin?"  Seriously, doing this sort of stuff is what we're here for.  If you're doing something shady, just stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) is it possible to set up 2-3
>   virtual hosts without a divine
>   intervention of our system
>   administrator? This actually I would
>   like to avoid it at all costs

No, apache's configuration needs to be updated and it needs to be restarted to activate virtualhosts. So unless your sysadmin has given you sudo access to do these things, you're out of luck.

> 2) I the answer for 1) is NO, what is
>   the easiest way to set up virtual
>   hosts. For example, can I register
>   subdomain1.example.com,
>   subdomain2.example.com etc in other
>   DNS servers?

No, you'll need to create the additional DNS records in the same place that's hosting DNS for example.com.

Comment: I have the root account on the machine where Apache  is installed, so this is not a problem.

Comment: Then for the apache piece, all you need to do is follow any one of the myriad apache virtualhost how-to guides kicking around here or elsewhere on the internet. That still won't help you with your DNS problem, though.

Comment: Depending on your DNS provider, it's possible to add the DNS record for *.example.com. For example goddady gives that choice.